# Design Guidance - How to push or reference properties from a MainViewModel to a ControlsViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

So I have a primary MainViewModel that collects and distributes a fair amount of real-time data (changes every .1 seconds). Currently all of my Controls are referencing my MainViewModel.

I'm using a UserControl Control to replicate many objects of the same type of Digital Gauge.

My question is, is there a best practice for "pushing" or "referencing" data from my MainViewModel to a ControlViewModel? The purpose I have in mind is to keep the DependencyProperties I need tucked away cleanly in a ControlViewModel and keep the MainViewModel as clean and tidy as possible.

Is MVVMLight Messaging an option?
Is an event appropriate?
Can I setup bindings from the ControlViewModel to the MainViewModel so when the MainViewModel data is updated, it gets reflected in the ControlViewModel?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Also, I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Salutations are slightly different than a "thanks" at the end of a question. See the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148696/158605). But I agree that tags should not be in the title :)

Comment: I find this site and the contributors so extremely valuable. My sincerest thank you to ALL who contribute. I hope one day I can also contribute in a meaningful way. THANK YOU stack overflow community!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, I think you may just want to create a property of that exposes a collection of `ControlViewModel`s in your `MainViewModel`:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public IEnumerable<ControlViewModel> Controls { get; private set; }
}
```

You can set this with all of the necessary `ControlViewModel` objects in the constructor. If you might add or remove gauges, change `IEnumerable` to `ObservableCollection`.

Then for your gauges, you'd use an `ItemsControl` and set `ItemsSource="{Binding Controls}"`. This will automatically make the `DataContext` for each item one of your `ControlViewModel`s.

To render the items with your gauge control, set the `ItemTemplate` on the `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourNamespace:ControlViewModel}">
        <YourNamespace:DigitalGauge />
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I will have to take some time to wrap my head around this. Haven't been this deep yet. Thank you for helping out.